# Random space when indexing in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

So whenever I try to run this function there is a space between the two values i want to print can anyone help?

```
def initials():
    dot = "."
    f = input("first name: ")
    s = input("last name: ")
    print(f[0],dot,s[0])
    
    
initials()
```

Answer (score 0):

A trailing comma will result in another space to be appended, but not with '+' operator.